# Getting the value of a value of a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I get the value of the cell in column `C` row `24-A1`, where `A1` is the cell A1.

For example, if the value in cell A1 is 4, I want to get the value of cell C20 as the row number is `24 - 4 = 20`.

The following fails with a `#NAME?` error:

```
=C$(24-A1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `INDIRECT` [function](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151323)

```
 =INDIRECT("C"&(24-A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the OFFSET [function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/offset-HP005209208.aspx)

=OFFSET(C24,-A1,0)

This will take the location of cell C24, subtract A1 from the row reference, and add 0 to the column reference.